# Upload de imagens android para pasta no Servidor

Tags: java, android, web-service, imagem, upload

Como posso fazer um upload de imagem do android para uma pasta no servidor? tenho o endereço da pasta que posso utilizar para salvar imagem, ja estou utilizando esse endereço para poder pegar as imagens só que agora preciso salvar imagens nessa pasta do servidor.

OBS: Meu web Service é feito em JAVA

Answer (score 3):

Para enviar qualquer informação para a web vc precisa fazer um request. Estou supondo que vc já tenha um servidor web ... existe uma lib muito simples e fácil de usar, chama refrofit. Ela realiza chamadas Rest. (http://square.github.io/retrofit/)
Ex da página

@Multipart
@PUT("/user/photo")
User updateUser(@Part("photo") TypedFile photo, @Part("description") TypedString description);

Não esqueça de colocar o método que faz o upload fora da thread de UI.

Comment: Nunca conhecia essa, mas pela documentação parece ser uma mão na roda!

Answer (score 1):

O manifest

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.androidexample.uploadtoserver"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.androidexample.uploadtoserver.UploadToServer"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

O Layout

```
     <TextView
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text=""
         android:id="@+id/messageText"
         android:textColor="#000000"
         android:textStyle="bold"
     />
   </LinearLayout>
```

O codigo Java:

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class UploadToServer extends Activity {

TextView messageText;
Button uploadButton;
int serverResponseCode = 0;
ProgressDialog dialog = null;

String upLoadServerUri = null;

/**********  File Path *************/
final String uploadFilePath = "/mnt/sdcard/";
final String uploadFileName = "service_lifecycle.png";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_to_server);

    uploadButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
    messageText  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messageText);

    messageText.setText("Uploading file path :- '/mnt/sdcard/"+uploadFileName+"'");

    /************* Php script path ****************/
    upLoadServerUri = "http://www.androidexample.com/media/UploadToServer.php";

    uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(UploadToServer.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
                                }
                            });                     

                         uploadFile(uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);

                    }
                  }).start();       
            }
        });
}

public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {


      String fileName = sourceFileUri;

      HttpURLConnection conn = null;
      DataOutputStream dos = null; 
      String lineEnd = "\r\n";
      String twoHyphens = "--";
      String boundary = "*****";
      int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
      byte[] buffer;
      int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
      File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

      if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

           dialog.dismiss();

           Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"
                               +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);

           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                   messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"
                           +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);
               }
           });

           return 0;

      }
      else
      {
           try {

                 // open a URL connection to the Servlet
               FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
               URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

               // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
               conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
               conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
               conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
               conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
               conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
               conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
               conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

               dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
               dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploaded_file";filename=""
                                         + fileName + """ + lineEnd);

               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

               // create a buffer of  maximum size
               bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

               bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
               buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

               // read file and write it into form...
               bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize); 

               while (bytesRead > 0) {

                 dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                 bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                 bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                 bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

                }

               // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

               // Responses from the server (code and message)
               serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
               String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

               Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                       + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

               if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                          +" http://www.androidexample.com/media/uploads/"
                                          +uploadFileName;

                            messageText.setText(msg);
                            Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "File Upload Complete.",
                                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });               
               }   

               //close the streams //
               fileInputStream.close();
               dos.flush();
               dos.close();

          } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

              dialog.dismiss(); 
              ex.printStackTrace();

              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                      Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "MalformedURLException",
                                                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              });

              Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex); 
          } catch (Exception e) {

              dialog.dismiss(); 
              e.printStackTrace();

              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                      Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ",
                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              });
              Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "
                                               + e.getMessage(), e); 
          }
          dialog.dismiss();      
          return serverResponseCode;

       } // End else block
     }
 }
```

O codigo PHP

```
    $file_path = "uploads/";

    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
        echo "success";
    } else{
        echo "fail";
    }
     ?>
```

Ao inves enviar a imagem com $_FILE (input file) e possivel enviar usando POST. Por isso precisa transformar a imagem numa "string" e transmitir numa variavel. Do lado do PHP o tratamento seria diferente ("decode" e depois criar o documento e salvar)

Comment: O exemplo acima falta uma liberação temporária de compartilhamento, sem ela não funciona.